# Consulta con MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Buenas tengo en la tabla inspections algunos select que tienen valores, para no tener que hardcodear todos los valores posibles a elegir los guarde en una tabla llamada form_values

Al guardar una inspection en el campo del picker se guarda la id de esa opcion

Al obtener los datos del formulario

Necesito que esos campos no me devuelva el id del valor sino el valor mismo que lo debe buscar por su id en la otra tabla

Supongo que sera con un inerjoin

Como podria hacer esta consulta?

Comment: muestra el codigo q tienes para ayudarte mejor

Comment: Es que no tengo, estoy por empezar a hacerlo y necesito la consulta MYSQL

Comment: En la tabla INSPECTIONS hay campos que contienen la id de el valor en  FORM_VALUES, necesito que al traer los datos en lugar de traer la id traiga el valor que corresponde a esa id en FORM_VALUES

Comment: `SELECT i.campo1, i.campo2, ... FROM Inspections i INNER JOIN Form_Values fv ON (i.picker = fv.id) WHERE <alguna condición>.`

Comment: ¿Podrías editar tu pregunta y agregar la estructura de tus tablas `inspections` y `form_values`?